# iPad case that blocks buttons

Tags: ipad

Does anyone know of an iPad case that blocks access to the physical buttons.  I would like the user to not be able to hit the homembutton or the sleep button.

Comment: Ducktape is your best friend :)

Comment: Not about a case - but checkout the guided access - https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509 - you can disable home and sleep with that in software, doesn't require a case :)

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for a [kiosk display](http://www.ipadenclosures.com) of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

there not cases on the market yet, I guess.
But you do can use your creativity and made the case yourself;)
For example like that:

http://carrypad.com/2010/04/15/how-to-make-an-ipad-booksafe-case/

Answer (score 0):

[BubCap home button covers](http://www.bubcap.com) block the home button and work with both iPhone and iPad:

[image]