# iPad case that can block the home button

Tags: ipad, hardware-recommendation, case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad case that blocks buttons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/ipad-case-that-blocks-buttons)

I'm making an app that is supposed to sit in a public space and so I'm looking for an iPad case that can block the home button from the users. Any suggestions?

Bonus: If it has an integrated credit

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: Do you mean an integrated credit-card *reader?* You're unlikely to find either of those features on any consumer case.